# Postfix send SMS - Debian

Tags: amazon-web-services, debian, postfix-mta

I have a little trouble make the configuration the postfix in a Debian Server, then i try make the sent from another IP diferent at local, using postfix have this error.

```
reject: RCPT from [direccion ip]: 454 4.7.1 <destinantario>: Relay access denied; from=<correoServer> to=<destinatario> proto=ESMTP helo=<dominio>
```

What configuration i forgotten o where is the mistake

this is my main.cf

```js
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
mydomain = dominio
myhostname = smtp.dominio
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, dominio, ip-172-31-36-15.us-east-2.compute.internal, localhost.us-east-2.compute.internal, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
resolve_numeric_domain = yes
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: `smtpd_relay_restrictions`. Are you using authentication to send the email?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for a week. I couldn't send to my domain, GMail or any other service from a server installed at a client location. I tried sendmail as well as postfix but kept getting this "relay denied" message.

What finally gave a clue was when I tried telnet. The banner I got was from the Sophos XG firewall installed there. Seems like this firewall intercepts SMTP communications. Adding a relay rule on the firewall was what got the mails to go through.